# Popup of AutoCompleteTextView is showing behind keyboard

Tags: android, popup, autocompletetextview

I have an **AutoCompleteTextView** in my app, at the bottom of the layout.
When user inputs data, suggestion popup with items should appear.
All works as expected on Android Samsung device with OS 6.0.1:

[image]

But for Android 8.0.0 (LG device and also an emulator 8.1.0), I don't see such popup, I suppose it showing behind keyboard for some reason (Because when I clicked back button nothing happened - popup handled that event, and only on second back click keyboard disappeared):

[image]

My AutocompleteTextview:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout ...
        <android.support.v7.widget.AutoCompleteTextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/thin_square_border"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:minHeight="60sp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/charcoalgray"

                />
       </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

I've tried dropDownAnchor on view above, and **android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"** but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution that works for me in Oreo and Pie. 
I added this to my fragment:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

This seems like a bug introduced in Oreo.  Hope this helps for your case.

Answer (score -1):

you have to set `android:dropDownAnchor="@id/container_comment"` in your autocomplete widget

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is id/container_comment? Did you just copy/pasted from somewhere without knowing yourself how this piece of code works?

Comment: sorry i forgoted. i use custom class of Autocomplete for make it can mention. edit my answer soon